# App engine: filter for value in list returns empty list

Tags: python, google-app-engine

What am I doing wrong??

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Owner(db.Model):
    things = db.ListProperty(db.Key)

class Thing(db.Model):
    pass

t1 = Thing(key_name='thing1')
t2 = Thing(key_name='thing2')
t1.put()
t2.put()

o = Owner(key_name='me')
o.things = [t1.key(), t2.key()]
o.put()

result = Owner.all().filter('things=',t1).fetch(10)
print result  # returns empty list!!
```

Comment: I dont follow what you are trying to do? Do you want a keylist of things owned by owner?

Comment: I want a list of owners who own thing1.

Comment: Are you an affiliate of Dr Suess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a space between the property name and the operator in the first filter argument.

Bad:

```
Owner.all().filter('things=',t1)
```

Good:

```
Owner.all().filter('things =',t1)
```